# Please help me evaluate the following integral analytically

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{5} \left(\arccos\left(\frac{2}{x+2}\right)\right)^2 \, dx
$$
I tried evaluating this integral using traditional techniques such as integration by parts,  u-substitution and trigonometric identities, however,
I was unsuccessful. If this integral is analytically derivable, please specify the technique or analysis framework that could yield results, including multivariable calculus, complex analysis or tricks (such as Feynman's trick). I would prefer a closed-form solution to this integral if possible, for the positive real numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with

$$I = \int \left[ \arccos{ \left( \frac{2}{x+2} \right)} \right]^2  \, dx,$$

change variables to

$$y = \arccos{ \left( \frac{2}{x+2} \right)}$$

to get

$$I = 2 \int y^2 \frac{\sin{y} \, dy}{\cos^2{y}},$$

which can be integrated by parts:

$$I = 2 \int y^2 \, d\left( \frac{1}{\cos{y}} \right) = \frac{2y^2}{\cos{y}} - 4J$$

where

$$J = \int \frac{y\,dy}{\cos{y}}.$$

To integrate $J$, express it as

$$J = 2 \int \frac{y\,dy}{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}$$

and change variables to

$$z = e^{iy}$$

to get

$$J = -2 \int \log{z}\,\frac{dz}{z^2 + 1}.$$

This can then also be integrated by parts:

$$J = -2 \int (\log{z}) \, d(\arctan(z)) = -2 (\log{z}) \arctan{z} + 2K$$

where

$$K = \int \frac{\arctan{z}}{z}\,dz.$$

Now use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)

$$\arctan{z} = -\frac{i}{2}\log\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$

to write

$$K = -\frac{i}{2} \left[ \int \frac{\log{(1+iz)}}{z} \, dz - \int \frac{\log{(1-iz)}}{z} \right]$$

and recognize these integrals as [dilogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function):

$$K = -\frac{i}{2} \left[ \text{Li}_2(iz) - \text{Li}_2(-iz) \right].$$

Assembling these results,

$$I = \frac{2y^2}{\cos{y}} + 4y \left[ \log{(1+ie^{iy})} - \log{(1-ie^{iy})} \right] + 4i \left[ \text{Li}_2(ie^{iy}) - \text{Li}_2(-ie^{iy}) \right]$$

where

$$y = \arccos{ \left( \frac{2}{x+2} \right)}.$$

Plotting $I$ between $x = 0$ and $x = 5$ reveals that it is in fact real and well-behaved. The value at $x = 0$ is $-7.32772$ and the value at $x = 5$ is $-1.77109$, giving $5.55664$ for the definite integral, in agreement with numeric evaluation of the original integral you asked about.

Comment: TYSM, could you please explain in simple terms what the dilogarithm is and convey me to a proof of the identities you have used. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The dilogarithm is a welll-investigated "special function", in the same way that, say, Bessel functions are special functions. It's defined as a simple infinite series. (If you expand $\log{(1-iz)}/z$ in a Taylor series and integrate, you'll get it.) I linked to the Wikipedia pages for it and for the trig identity.

Comment: If you want to "accept" my answer, there should be a check mark that you can click.

Comment: Hi @Ghoster, I just wanted to clarify how you plotted this function and evaluated the bounds with all of the complex arguments and terms?

Comment: I have a subscription to the Home Edition of Mathematica, but SageMath and NumPy are free and may be able to do this as well.

Comment: Did your integral come from somewhere or did you just make it up as practice? If you are making up integrals, be aware that there is no guarantee that a random integral can be expressed in terms of functions that have been given names.

Comment: Yes, I constructed this integral to calculate the volume of revolution of a wine glass as part of my mathematics folio. Could using double integrals or triple integrals in cylindrical coordinates simplify the volume computation, as the original function f(x) = 2csc(x/2+pi/2)-2 is symmetrical about the y axis? Thanks.

Comment: That seems like a separate question. It isn’t clear to me how that function relates to the integral in this question.

Comment: I found the inverse of this preceding function and posted the integral of the volume of revolution of the inverse function, but I removed the constant terms as I just wanted to know how to analytically solve the core integral.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \left(\arccos\left(\frac{2}{x+2}\right)\right)^2 \, dx$$
Let $t=\frac{2}{x+2}$
$$I=2\int \frac{ \big[\cosh ^{-1}(t)\big]^2}{t^2}\,dt$$
$$I=-\frac 2t \Bigg[\cosh ^{-1}(t) \left(\cosh ^{-1}(t)+4 t \cot ^{-1}\left(e^{\cosh
   ^{-1}(t)}\right)\right)-2 i t \left(\text{Li}_2\left(i e^{-\cosh
   ^{-1}(t)}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-i e^{-\cosh ^{-1}(t)}\right)\right)\Bigg]$$  No way to avoid the polylogarithms.

If you want a series solution, write
$$\big[\cosh ^{-1}(t)\big]^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\, t^n$$ where
$$a_n=\frac {(n-2)^2} {n(n-1)}a_{n-2} \quad\quad  \text{with}\quad\quad  a_0=-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\quad \quad a_1=\pi\quad\quad a_2=1$$ Integrating termwise
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n-1}\, t^{n-1}$$

Using the given bounds
$$J=\int_0^5 \left(\arccos\left(\frac{2}{x+2}\right)\right)^2 \, dx=-5 a_0-2 a_1 \log \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)-\frac{10 }{7}a_2+$$ $$
2\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n-1}\,\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)^{n-1}\right)$$ Computing the partial sum after the expansion to $O(t^{k+1})$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \text{partial sum} \\
 10 & 5.56163 \\
 20 & 5.55774 \\
 30 & 5.55707 \\
 40 & 5.55685 \\
 50 & 5.55676 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty &5.55664
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Can you please explain in further detail how you arrived at your series solution and how you evaluated the bounds. I am at a calc 2/3 level, so a simplification of the derivation process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ramanujan007. It is a basic Taylor expansion. What has been hard was to find the recurrence relation for the $a_n$'s. The remaining is simple.

Comment: How did you extract the recurrence relation and could you please convey a resource explaining the resolution of integrals using series representations? Also, what identity did you use to transform the original integral to the inverse cosh integral? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the substitution $\cos\theta=\frac{2}{x+2}$ then you get

$$ dx=2\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta $$

and the integral becomes

$$ \int_0^{\arccos(2/7)}2\theta^2\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$$

I suspect Feynman's trick will work on this version since Wolfram gives an antiderivative. But it is not pretty:

[image: Result from Wolfram]

[image: Corresponding definite integral]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please demonstrate the steps for the application of Feynman's trick to the substituted integral, such that the result matches Wolfram Alpha's complex valued output?

Comment: I don't know the steps. When I saw Wolfram's response I realized it would be beyond my 80 year old brain at 2:30 AM in the morning. Perhaps someone else will try to solve it.